# html page size problem with no of dom elements increase

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Recently we redesigned one of our pages and suddenly page has been increased from 1MB to 1.98MB.

I compared the no of DOM elements and its increased from 1600 to 2300. I found the no of elements from the below command

```
document.getElementsByTagName('*').length
```

We did a load test and found the load time also increased from 1.1 to 2 seconds. Is this the reason for all problems.

I think the above line won't consider any inline css and js right , as they are not DOM elements.

Can you please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript that runs can manipulate the dom and create new nodes which would affect your count.  However it shouldn't make the page load any slower as it's rendered on the client side.

I think you need to include more information if you expect to get a better answer.

Also you should look into browser plugins (for firefox) like Yslow, or firebug (net tab) that show you all the files being loaded and how long they load.

Comment: @superfro, i did all those research with YSLOW, pagespeed etc.Now we are trying to implement fileaggregation etc based on those suggestions

Comment: Is your html output driven by a scripting language ? ASP ? PHP ?  Maybe the page is simply larger because of the data being output ?  Maybe it has images that change, and the images being uploaded are a lot larger then they used to be?  Do you have a sample of the old html output versus the new one, that you could do a simple 'diff' on and see whats been added ?  Your question is still quite ambiguous, are we talking about _ONLY_ the actual html, no linked files / js /css /images / object embeds ?

Comment: @superfro ,its a combination of .net and asp , jquery and css ,javscript. the present on is www.allposters.com  home page , the redesigned one is not yet live.

Comment: @superfro , can you tell me what should be the optimal page size and what are all contributes to the page size

Comment: The most optimal page size is going to be one that loads the fastest for your users.  If you are saying the page loads slow because of all elements, html, js, css, images, and embedded object content, then you _REALLY_ need to re-think your optimization.  Maybe your HTML being spit out is too large (unlikely the problem), maybe your images need to be optimized, maybe you are loading too many images and should implement a lazy load image system (google lazy load images).  I'm sorry but your question is just way too broad to answer correctly with the info you have given.

Comment: @superfro, thanks for all the directions. one more question ,where can i see the page size, is it just file save page as and see the file size or we can see somewhere from firebug

Comment: If you goto the 'Net' tab in firebug,  clear the results, refresh the page, the first 'url' will be the plain HTML of the page, it will show a size column, this is the size of the html output from the server, and each one of these files has been loaded to render the page.  you can click on the size column and sort by size and see which files are the largest and start figuring out how you can make them smaller or load after the page is rendered to speed up the site.

Comment: @superfro...thanks very much , this is what i want. I want to see the difference between production and qa environment...for the plain html.I got it...The plain html itself there is a huge difference for us.Thanks once again. i will mark yours as answer

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing exactly what you redesigned, it's impossible to know what change caused the increase. But even a 1MB page is pretty large. JavaScript (and particularly jQuery) can change the number of DOM objects... consider this:

```
$('p').append('<span>Blah</span> <span>blah</span> <span>blah</span>');
```

That will add 3 DOM objects for each p tag on the page (which could be a lot!) and yet it adds only 71 bytes to your page. jQuery can similarly remove DOM objects. So I don't think the number of DOM objects is really much of a consideration.

Comment: I want to know what contributes to the page size calculation??

Comment: It's the size of the source of the page. Click view source in your browser... the number of characters shown there, plus the number of characters of any included Javascript, images, etc is the number of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime that you have more information crossing the wire, it will take longer.  Therefore, with more DOM elements in the page, the loading time will be slower.  I hope this answers your question because I'm not really sure of what you are actually asking.

Comment: we are trying to find the reasons why page size has been increased. Just want to know if no of dom elements are directly proportional page size of the page.

Comment: `I'm not really sure of what you are actually asking.` +1 for this :)